# Ionic Keyboard doesn't work on input / textarea fields in Salesforce1 on iOS

Tags: ios, salesforce, ionic-framework, visualforce

I'm developing a mobile web app using Ionic and Salesforce1. One part of my app has a super simple form (2 inputs and a text area). The form works great on every device and browser except for within Salesforce1 on iOS. When I tap to focus on a any of these fields - keyboard pops up but nothing I type gets outputted to the input field or textarea.

A few observations...

- [It may have something to do with ionic being run inside of the Salesforce1 iframe container](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/salesforce1-ionic-application-ios-keyboard-not-working/5657/11)
- It does work on mobile safari, when it is not in the salesforce1 iframe
- I was able to get `< input >` fields working by inserting `window.focus()` into the top of the ionic method `tapHandleFocus(ele)`
- Using Siri for voice input seems to work.
- As I type, the keyboard will show suggested autocomplete words. If i tap these words, they are inserted into the fields as expected.
- Once there is text in the field, it is possible to edit the field as expected.
- My hunch/guess is that my initial tap focuses on a duplicated field that floats above/under/behind the shown (an Ionic thing). For some reasons typing individual characters isn't successfully putting the values in the shown field??

Let me know if there's any other info I can provide to be more helpful.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution of this problem yet? I have the same problem in salesforce1 on iOS. I think the fields get unfocused because the keyboard slides on top of them.

Comment: I have not found a complete solution yet. I've gotten input fields working by editting ionic.js but text areas are still broken. Instructions for getting input fields working is here  http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-edit-the-input-fields-edit-video/7268/18

Comment: Hey @colin, this seems to be working now. Not sure if it was something Salesforce did, but appears to be working now. How about for you?

Comment: Hi @Austin, I have had contact with Salesforce and they sent me this url: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3iBAAS
They said they were aware of the problem so I think they actually fixed it already, good to hear it's working for you too now.

Comment: I don't have the `tapHandleFocus` method in my ionic.js. What version are you using?